# Can we add class attribute in option element?

Tags: html, attributes, html-select

I want to add class for my option element. Is that valid to add class attribute in HTML option element?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is valid.

From the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) website:

```
The <option> tag also supports the Global Attributes in HTML.
```

From which the `class` attribute is a part of. Please note that often, the `option` tag has formatting issues regarding the browser you are using, so styling it can be a little tricky.

**EDIT:** Since I wrote this answer, it has come to my attention that [W3Schools probably isn't the most reliable source](http://www.w3fools.com/) of *good* information. The previous answer isn't at all wrong, but it came from a source that has proven to be somewhat inconsistent/incomplete. As such, I think I should also append a more *official* link to this subject [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option).

Answer (score 4):

The `class` attribute is valid for `option` according to the [relevant part](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) of the HTML 4.01 Recommendation. The HTML5 drafts, including HTML5 CR, are even more permissive: they allow `class` literally [on any element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes).

My guess is that what you really wanted to ask was whether you can style some `option` elements differently from others, using `class` attributes and CSS. Then the answer is that this depends on browser – not due to problems with recognizing `class` attributes but due to implementations of that are partly immune to CSS as regards to styling items in a dropdown list.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes!

In HTML it is valid to add a `class` attribute to an `option` element <sup>[[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)]</sup>.

#### However...

For **CSS implications** though, the usability is limited. Especially when it comes to the `option` tag because it is subject to the operating system's form control handlers <sup>[[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms#Why_is_it_so_hard_to_style_form_widgets_with_CSS)]</sup>. This is the reason why code sample below **will not** actually work across all browsers.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>Centaur</option>
    <option class="colored">Unicorn</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.colored {
    background-image: url('my-colorful-background.png'); // e.g.: Apple doesn't recognize this rule
}
```

For **JavaScript implications** (w/jQuery), the usability is fully supported when it comes to the DOM objects but still bounded with the CSS implications as stated above. Thus, DOM-manipulation code like so... will work.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>Centaur</option>
    <option class="colored">Unicorn</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript with jQuery

```
var label = jQuery('.colored').html();
console.log( label ); // outputs Unicorn
```

#### References

1. **W3C** - [HTML 4.01 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/), [Forms, The SELECT, OPTGROUP, and OPTION elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)
2. **MDN** - [Styling HTML forms, Why is it so hard to style form widgets with CSS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms#Why_is_it_so_hard_to_style_form_widgets_with_CSS)

Answer (score 1):

Yes `class` belongs to global attributes. Any element can have it.

Source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global