# Django: How to add dynamic classes to select options in a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I have a ModelForm that I'm rendering in the template with django-widget-tweaks. I have a ChoiceField select that prints out something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="object.id">object.name</option>
</select>
```

But for Javascript manipulation purposes, I need the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="object.id" class="object.otherPropery">object.name</option>
</select>
```

[django-widget-tweaks has an add_class function](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks#add-class), but it only adds a class to the select box, not the contained options.

I have also tried rolling my own select box:

```
<select>
    {% for object in form.object_field %}
        <option value="{{ object.id }}" class="{{ object.otherProperty }}">{{ object.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But when the form does not validate and errors are returned, the option the user had selected previously gets reset back to the default (first) option (this *does* happen with django-widget-tweaks).

I have also tried overriding the `render_option` and `render_options` fields of the Select widget, but the additional properties of the object are not being passed to those functions.

I feel like there's a simple solution for what I'm trying to do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this (note the 'if' tag):

```
<select>
    {% with value=form.object_field.value %}
        {% for object in form.object_field %}
            <option 
                value="{{ object.id }}" 
                class="{{ object.otherProperty }}"
                {% if object.id == value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
            >
                {{ object.name }}
            </option>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
</select>
```

Although the if condition might not result in a true result when it should, if the `object.id` is a integer because the `value` would always be a string for a already submitted form (all the values in the POST/GET query data are strings). But if the value comes from the 'initial_data' it would be integer.

For such cases you may update your 'if' tag as follows:

```
{% if object.id|slugify == value|slugiy %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
```

Making the final code as follows:

```
<select>
    {% with value=form.object_field.value %}
        {% for object in form.object_field %}
            <option 
                value="{{ object.id }}" 
                class="{{ object.otherProperty }}"
                {% if object.id|slugify == value|slugify %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
            >
                {{ object.name }}
            </option>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

`render_option` has been removed from Django 1.11 onwards. This is what I did to achieve this. A little bit of digging and this seems straightforward. Works with Django 2.0+

```
class CustomSelect(forms.Select):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
        self.custom_attrs = {}
        super().__init__(attrs, choices)

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
        index = str(index) if subindex is None else "%s_%s" % (index, subindex)
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        option_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs) if self.option_inherits_attrs else {}
        if selected:
            option_attrs.update(self.checked_attribute)
        if 'id' in option_attrs:
            option_attrs['id'] = self.id_for_label(option_attrs['id'], index)

        # setting the attributes here for the option
        if len(self.custom_attrs) > 0:
            if value in self.custom_attrs:
                custom_attr = self.custom_attrs[value]
                for k, v in custom_attr.items():
                    option_attrs.update({k: v})

        return {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
            'label': label,
            'selected': selected,
            'index': index,
            'attrs': option_attrs,
            'type': self.input_type,
            'template_name': self.option_template_name,
        }


class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    # custom method to label the option field
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        # since the object is accessible here you can set the extra attributes
        if hasattr(obj, 'type'):
            self.widget.custom_attrs.update({obj.pk: {'type': obj.type}})
        return obj.get_display_name()
```

The form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    customer = MyModelChoiceField(required=True,
                                  queryset=Customer.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('name'),
                                  widget=CustomSelect(attrs={'class': 'chosen-select'}))
```

The output which I needed is as:

```
  <select name="customer" class="chosen-select" required="" id="id_customer">
      <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
      <option value="242" type="CNT">AEC Transcolutions Private Limited</option>
      <option value="243" type="CNT">BBC FREIGHT CARRIER</option>
      <option value="244" type="CNT">Blue Dart Express Limited</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are problems with adding classes or anything else to option elements.  I know the applies for CSS for certain, see this other post for example: [Can we add class attribute in option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438697/can-we-add-class-attribute-in-option-element)
I think the same might apply to manipulating it with JavaScript.

It might be a little tricky, but maybe in the template make it write out some JavaScript that maps the {{ object.id }} to the {{ object.otherProperty }}, so you have access to the value that way.