# how to do a nested multi select tree in django

Tags: jquery, django, tree, multi-select

How can I do a nested multi select tree using django model form and the select tree will have more than 400 items

I've been searching on the internet but I didn't find something suitable for this problem, Does anyone has a tutorial that I can read ?

thanks in advance.

This is my model

```
class CNPQ(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nome da Área de conhecimento", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name="Descrição da Área de conhecimento" ,max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    level  = models.TextField(verbose_name="Nível")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

what I want is to do this but using django and jquery

[image]

based in the level from my table

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by nested tree ? What values will you choose between, other models ?

Comment: sorry for my explanation, I'm using just one table to create an tree and it will have levels that will identify if the items are parent or siblings.  I was trying this https://github.com/patosai/tree-multiselect.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com but I got a problem with data-section, I could not add data section with a specific name to make it nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add data-section attribute to your options, you'll need to override the `create_option()` method of the Select widget in your ModelForm. More documentation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654199/django-how-to-add-dynamic-classes-to-select-options-in-a-form) and [here](https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2017/10/16/add-data-attributes-option-tags-django-admin-select-field/).

Comment: Thanks Mehdi B it helped me a lot