# Which kind of attribute can support a html element?

Tags: jquery, html

Can ALL html components (elements and tab) support ALL kind attributes?
For example:
Is it possible to add a attribute *class* to a `<option>` tab from a `<select>` element?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438697/can-we-add-class-attribute-in-option-element

(Only global attributes not ALL)

Comment: You can use data- prefix for custom attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No is the answer, they don't all accept every possible attribute, but there are global attributes such as `class` which do apply to all tags.

If you look at the specification for the elements on W3, you can see the attributes (including global attributes) that a tag can accept.

**Here's the spec for `<select>`:**
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-select-element.html

The attributes that a tag can have is dependent on the version of HTML that you're using (as defined within your `<!DOCTYPE>`) and I would imagine the browser compliance with the spec.

It's also worth noting that you can have your own custom attributes which start with `data-` in order to store your own values. EG:

```
<select data-animal-type="elephant">
```

As stated in the comments it isn't *invalid* to have additional attributes, but they don't necessarily serve a purpose other than how they are utilized by the developer.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped

Answer (score 2):

You can see it **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)** what kind of `attributes` are accepted by what type of `elements`.

and for your question - `option` can have `class` attribute since it is a **[`Global_Attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)**

Answer (score 0):

Not all html components support all attributes.
For option, you cannot add class... But still you can apply css...Please check this below post  [option css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Comment: What makes you think you cannot add class to option? Please check your information about attributes via http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML the are some global attributes that are accepted by almost all html tags, but there are some attributes that are especially for one kind of tag. For example you cant use the "autofocus" attribute in a "p" tag.

The  tag could support the class attribute and the  tag as well. Cause according to the W3SCHOOL both of them accept global attribute.

Heres some documentation that will help you a lot:

- [HTML ATTRIBUTES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

And for the next time if you will like to know what attributed could a tag support you just have to look the tag at the [W3 SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/) And at the bottom of the page you will see what kind of attributed could the tag support(you will see a capture on this answers that will show you what im talking about).

For example:

Heres the select tag reference:[SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

As you can see at the bottom of the article you will see all the attribute(general attributes, global attributes, event attributes) for the select tag.[image: ATTRIBUTES FOR SELECT]