# AngularJS: use ng-class in ng-options for the option tag (not for the select tag)

Tags: angularjs

i have ng-option line and i want to use ng-class to apply at the option tag not at the select tag. 
the constraint is that i use option property as condition and there is not option tag, it will be rendered by ng-option mechanism

```
<select ng-class="ClassNameToApply:obj.rtl" multiple size="20" style="width: 100%" ng-model="someModel" ng-options="obj.objId as obj.objName for obj in objList |filter: SomeFilter"></select>
```

Comment: did you see this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options

Comment: Rendering select-options by class may not have desired effect in browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438697/can-we-add-class-attribute-in-option-element